# Beer song excercise

Tags: java, 99-bottles-of-beer

I'm reading the book Head First Java and got an assignment to re-create the [99 Bottles of Beer](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/lyrics.html) song according to those lyrics found in the URL. I've had to do this with a Java while loop.

```
class SecondBeerSong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int beerBottles = 99;
        String word;
        while(beerBottles >= 0) {
            word = "bottles";
            if(beerBottles != 0) {
                System.out.println(beerBottles + " " + word + " of beer on the wall, "+ beerBottles + " " + word + " of beer." );
                beerBottles--;

                if(beerBottles == 1) {
                    word = "bottle";
                }

                if(beerBottles > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, " + beerBottles + " " + word +" of beer on the wall.");           
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, no more " + word +" of beer on the wall.");           
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more " + word + " of beer on the wall, no more " + word + " of beer.");
                System.out.println("Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

My problems with the code:

- Lack of readability

  - To many if statements for string building
- It's confusing
- Not "object-oriented"
- The `while` loop gets ended with a `break`

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: My local PC is, but the book is teaching me Java 7 if im not mistaken

Comment: One reason why I asked about Java 8 is to consider if there's any Java 8-related features to aid in the looping... ultimately, I decided to come up with [my question here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111583/99-times-drunk-on-java) based on the concerns you raised, so maybe you can compare mine with yours. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Move something outside of the loop**

The main problem is that you are handling 0 and 1 bottles inside the loop, therefore making the whole loop more convoluted for one-shot conditions.

I suggest a loop to handle 99 to 2 and handling 1 and 0 manually:

```
for (int n = 99; n >= 2; n--) {
     System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, " + n + " bottles of beer on the wall.");           
     System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around, " + (n - 1) + " more bottles of beer on the wall.");
}

System.out.println("1 and 0 bottles text, verbatim");
```

**`for` loop**

As you have seen above, I used a `for` loop as it is recommended over `while` when you already know how many times you'll loop as it groups together start, condition and step. Making the code shorter and more organized.

Comment: Why should I handle 1 and 0 manually though? I'd like the dynamic way though. Is it bad to handle conditions inside a loop?

Comment: @Bas you are already handling them manually, when you do `if(beerBottles == 1) {
                    word = "bottle";
                }` or `if(beerBottles > 0) {` you are making making changes to the predefined printing message. It is cleaner to do it after the loop.

Comment: Also outright better since you're not evaluating two conditions that are only met once each.

Comment: @Legato please be careful about micro-optimization, it is easy to fall into their trap. I moved that out of the loop **only** because it was cleaner, saving 0.0001 seconds did not influence me the littlest in making this decision.

Comment: An appreciated admonishment and definitely something to keep in mind. Previous comment more of an understanding issue noted due to asker's probable novicehood serving to point out a technical benefit in following your advice, however marginal.

Comment: Almost! There is a pluralization bug when you go from 2 bottles to 1 bottle left.

Comment: @200_success True, the laziest fix would be to move even 2 bottles out of the loop.

Comment: So how would it be suggested doing the last 2 bottles? with just static `println`'s?

Answer (score 1):

There are two learning objectives to this programmers' etude: looping and pluralization.  @Caridorc has already addressed looping: use a for-loop, and extract the termination case out of the loop.

You tried to do pluralization, but you have a bug:

> ```
> 2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.
> Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.
>
> 1 bottles of beer on the wall, 1 bottles of beer.
> Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.
> ```

One approach to addressing the pluralization issue would be to define a function.  However, I would like to point out that pluralization is a common [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n) problem that has a [standard solution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html).  Therefore, I recommend going with the standard solution rather than reinventing the wheel.

```java
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class ThirdBeerSong {
    private static final String VERSE_FMT =
        "{0,choice," +
          "0#No more bottles|" +
          "1#1 bottle|" +
          "1<{0} bottles} of beer on the wall, " +
        "{0,choice," +
          "0#no more bottles|" +
          "1#1 bottle|" +
          "1<{0} bottles} of beer.\n" +
        "{1,choice," +
          "0#Go to the store and buy some more|" +
          "0<Take one down and pass it around}, " +
        "{1,choice," +
          "0#99 bottles|" +
          "1#1 bottle|" +
          "1<{1} bottles} of beer on the wall.\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int b = 99; b > 1; b--) {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(VERSE_FMT, b, b - 1));
        }
        System.out.print(MessageFormat.format(VERSE_FMT, 1, 0));
    }
}
```

If you find it acceptable to have an extra newline at the end of the output, you could get rid of the `System.out.print()` special case.

In the template, `0#99 bottles` is admittedly an abusive hack.  You can rework it if it bothers you.

Comment: I really have no idea what's happening here inside the `VERSE_FMT` string...

Comment: `{0}` and `{1}` are placeholders for the parameters `b` and `b - 1`, respectively. `{0,choice,…}` means to make a choice based on the first parameter (`b`). `{0,choice,0#No more bottles|1#1 bottle|1<{0} bottles}` means to make a choice based on `b`: if `b` is 0 then substitute "No more bottles", if `b` is 1 then substitute "1 bottle", and if `b > 1` then substitute "_b_ bottles".

Comment: I'm going to save this answer for later. I think it's to complicated for me at this moment in my java learning.

Answer (score -2):

**Beer Code:**

Improved your code using **ternary expressions**.

```
class SecondBeerSong {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word;
    for (int beers = 10; beers > 0; beers--) {

        word = (beers == 1) ? " bottle" : " bottles";
        System.out.println(beers + word + " of beer on the wall, " + beers + word + " of beer.");

        word = ((beers == 1) ? " no more bottles" : (beers - 1) + (beers - 1 == 1 ? " bottle" : " bottles"));
        System.out.println("Take one down and pass it around," + word + " of beer on the wall.\n");

    }

    System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.");
    System.out.println("Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.");

}
}
```

Comment: Hi, try to elaborate on the way you improved the code. Don't post answers with only a series of changes. This might not help the OP understand why this is better code.

Comment: The first `word` excludes the number, whereas the second `word` incorporates the number. I find the inconsistency annoying.